# template strings not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, template-strings

Template Strings should work on any terminals such as visual studio code terminal or windows terminal. But it didn't. I did this code visual studio code. Here is My code

```js
var name = 'Andrew';
console.log('Hello ${name}');
```

and the output is

```
Hello ${name}
```

Please specify changes in my code needed and explain why it doesn't work currently.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Single and double quotes wont invoke the behavior - use back ticks.

```js
var name = 'Andrew';
console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
//          ^             ^
```

More information on [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals),

Answer (score 2):

All that is inside a string, is literal. You're writing the variable ${name} inside the normal quotes, so it will be printed literal.
If you want to have it interpretated, you have to concatenate the answer, as for example:

console.log('Hello ' + name)

The quotes to use a template are not the ones you are using, these are the correct ones: (closed accents / back-tick )

```
`Hello ${name}`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

```js
var name = 'Andrew';
console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
```

Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions. You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the ES2015 specification.

Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (``)  (grave accent) character instead of double or single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a quote, nor double quote

```
var name = 'Andrew'
console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
```

Here is a tutorial about it: https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#template-strings